# C# / MonoTouch: how to call an async method when a ViewController is created/appears

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, async-await

Xamarin [released](http://blog.xamarin.com/major-upgrades-to-xamarin%E2%80%99s-platform-async-is-here/) support for `async`/`await` which really simplifies the development of responsive UI in mobile platforms. I'd like to take advantage of it and increase the programming level of my code by using async/await stuff from now on.

However, since I'm relatively new to C# and haven't used `async`/`await` before I'm having trouble to find 'hooks' in my code that I can invoke `async` methods. I know that event handlers are the typical places (where IoC happens), but imagine the following scenario:

I want to start  background task **when a ViewController is loaded** (as opposed to **when a button is pressed**).

```
async Task PerformMyTaskAsync ()
{
    // ...
    await ... // another async API
    // ...
}

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // .. initialize UI
    await PerformMyTaskAsync ();
}
```

Obviously I can't await for `PerformMyTaskAsync` in `ViewDidLoad` because `ViewDidLoad` is neither an async method nor an event handler.

What is the 'alternative' approach to start a background task when a view controller loads (or appears, whatever) ?

Comment: Check out a webinar by Miguel on Async http://blog.xamarin.com/csharp-async-on-ios-and-android/

Comment: I watched it live yesterday. Such a great explanation done by Miguel, but not covering exactly what I'm asking for. Thanks for the link anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The newest Xamarin Stable Channel releases support Async/Await overloads for ViewController Lifecycle methods.  Try:

```
public async override void ViewDidLoad()
```

Comment: And what about the warning that the method shouldn't return void if async?

Comment: @Chucky Usually you *never* want to return void from an async method to avoid many problems, hence the warning. The only exceptions are for event handlers and, in this case, lifecycle methods (so in this case you're OK to ignore the warning). Make sure to wrap any code within the async void in a try-catch.

Comment: For a generalized pattern of how to use multiple async Xamarin ViewController lifecycle methods in serial (to avoid some gotchas with async void), check out [my related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41270560/3312114)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "best" approach, but have you tried firing an event from within ViewDidLoad(), and then in the handler for that event launching your Async code?

Comment: Looks like a nice workaround, I haven't seen any other code doing that, but maybe this becomes a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

So, running something async off the UI thread, from an event, looks like this:

```
Blah.OnEvent += onEvent;

protected async void onEvent(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
...
}
```

The `void` is not a typo - it's the antipattern that Xamarin follows for async UI events, unfortunately.

There are valid scenarios where you would want to run an async method that makes the UI wait. For example, calling `Navigation.PushAsync()` off of a button click. But, you specifically asked for a background task, which implies it could take a while. For that, you don't want to make the UI wait; you should start the task and return immediately. For that you just use the same background task code you'd use in any C# TPL app:

```
    public static void RunBg(Func<Task> fn)
    {
        Task.Run(fn).ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Uncomment to roll up exceptions
            //.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static void RunBgLong(Func<Task> fn)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(fn, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Uncomment to roll up exceptions
            //.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

I provide both because the creators of the TPL have gone out of their way to provide both underneath the hood. The meaning of the 2 is better explored in other questions, though I believe the distinction for "long" is a small number of milliseconds.

So, you'd start your task like:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    TaskHelper.RunBg(async () => {
        await someBgAsyncMethodGoesHere(arg1, arg2);
    );
}
```