# Xamarin Async ViewDidAppear called during ViewDidLoad

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, async-await

I'm trying to initialize a view model on ViewDidLoad. I need to call some async methods in the ViewModel initialization code, so I've moved the async code out of the constructor into an [async factory method](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

I've marked the `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewWillAppear` as `async void` in my UIViewController subclass, but for some reason while line 4 is executing the `ViewWillAppear` is kicked off and line 11 throws a `NullReferenceException` because the ViewModel isn't initialized yet.

My suspicion is that Xamarin can't wait for ViewDidLoad to complete because it's `async void`, but I have to use an `async void` here because it's overriding a method.

MyCustomUiViewController.cs

```
1  public override async void ViewDidLoad()
2  {
3      base.ViewDidLoad();
4      ViewModel = await ViewModel.CreateAsync();
5      OtherStuff();
6  }
7 
8  public override async void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
9  {
10     base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
11     ViewModel.SomeMethod(); // <-- NullReferenceException
12     AttachViewModelToViewBindings();
13 }
```

I'm open to changing the architecture if there is a better pattern for instantiating an async ViewModel.

Comment: You marked the functions async, but that does not mean they ever get awaited. Not sure if that is it, but perhaps?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you found any workaround for it?

Comment: @ZeaShah I added an answer below that may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the generalized pattern that we used (extracted into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/seanfisher/66bdf388351c1c2a18931deac986bbff)). This lets you create a controller that inherits from `AsyncInitializationController` and then overrides, for example, `ViewDidLoadAsync`. The code is structured so that each subsequent lifecycle method waits for the previous ones to complete.

While we didn't have a need for an async `ViewDidDisappear`, I'm sure you could work that into this pattern as well.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UIKit;

namespace Seanfisher.Gists
{
    public abstract class AsyncInitializationController : UIViewController
    {
        Task _viewDidLoadAsyncTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        public virtual Task ViewDidLoadAsync()
        {
            return _viewDidLoadAsyncTask;
        }

        public sealed override async void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            try
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad();
                _viewDidLoadAsyncTask = ViewDidLoadAsync();
                await _viewDidLoadAsyncTask;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle
            }
        }

        Task _viewWillAppearAsyncTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        public virtual Task ViewWillAppearAsync()
        {
            return _viewWillAppearAsyncTask;
        }

        public sealed override async void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            try
            {
                await _viewDidLoadAsyncTask;
                base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
                _viewWillAppearAsyncTask = ViewWillAppearAsync();
                await _viewWillAppearAsyncTask;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle
            }
        }

        Task _viewDidAppearAsyncTask = Task.CompletedTask;
        public virtual Task ViewDidAppearAsync()
        {
            return _viewDidAppearAsyncTask;
        }
        public sealed override async void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            try
            {
                await _viewDidLoadAsyncTask;
                await _viewWillAppearAsyncTask;

                base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
                _viewDidAppearAsyncTask = ViewDidAppearAsync();
                await _viewDidAppearAsyncTask;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Handle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you mark ViewDidLoad as async, UI thread will not wait for ViewDidLoad as a whole (inside the ViewDidLoad function it will wait as long as you put await keyword). So UI thread will go to ViewWillAppear very fast(while your async web request inside the ViewDidLoad is still executing), thus ViewModel is still null.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31312523)

Answer (score -2):

Bodangly is right.

The methods wont be called asynchrounsly just because you mark them async.

Furthermore - "async void" should always be avoided. Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

A better pattern to solve this is explained here:
http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Which should be something like this: (Untested)

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
   base.ViewDidLoad();
   Initialization = InitializeAsync();

   OtherStuff();
}

public Task Initialization { get; private set; }

private async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    // Do our own initialization (synchronous or asynchronous).
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Comment: "async void should **always** be avoided" is a little too strong. In this case `async void` is unavoidable. From the article you linked to: "Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make asynchronous event handlers possible." and "It’s clear that async void methods have several disadvantages [...] but they’re quite useful in one particular case: asynchronous event handlers." That's exactly the case here - ViewDidLoad is an async event handler. The issue is when two async event handlers are called in succession and the second depends on the first being completed.